# Image from URL with .zip ending

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsurlsession, nsurl

I got a URL from which I need to extract an image. The image is PNG, however the URL look like this:

http://something.../something.zip

If I open this URL in safari, it automatically downloads a PNG. However when I try to load in my program I get a nil UIImage object.

My code:

```
- (void)fetchImageFromURL: (NSString *)urlString {
    NSURL *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
            
        } else {
            if (data) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
                if (image) {
                    [self.randomImageImageView setImage: image];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Image is nil.");
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Could not retrieve data.");
            }
        }
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Safari automatically unzips zip files if they're under a certain size. This means that you'd need to first unzip the file programmatically then locate your image from there.

Comment: That's brilliant. Had no idea that Safari does the automatically. Thanks!

Comment: FYI https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/961/how-to-stop-safari-from-unzipping-files-after-download